# Matlab define several step functions

Tags: matlab, function

I would like to define a Matlab function like the one shown in the figure below, but repeating regularly along the t axis.

[image]

So far I tried two different codes:

```
    function Borne = borne(p)
    pxt = x;
    Borne = zeros(size(pxt));
    i0 = (pxt <= 0.1);
    i1 = (pxt > 0.1 & pxt < 0.3);
    i2 = (pxt > 0.3 & pxt < 0.5);
    i3 = (pxt > 0.5 & pxt < 0.7);
    i4 = (pxt > 0.7 & pxt < 0.9);
    i5 = (pxt > 0.9 & pxt < 1.1);
    Borne(i0) = 3;
    Borne(i1) = -1;
    Borne(i2) = 3;
    Borne(i3) = -1;
    Borne(i4) = 3;
    Borne(i5) = -1;
```

This one works, but I might be obliged to go to time=100 perhaps.

```
    function Borne = borne(p)
    x=0:0.2:100;
    y=ones(1,length(x));
    for i=1:length(x)
      if mod(i,2) == 1;
        y(i)=3;
      else
        y(i)=-1;
      end
    end
    Borne=stairs(x,y);
```

This one doesn't work at all, it gives me a constant function at 147 circa. Also, at the end of the for loop both x and y have length=1, and I don't know why.

Is there a better way to define my function, maybe? If not, how can I improve my codes?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it one-shot with the remainder (`rem`) function and logical indexing:

```
%// Data
period = 1;
up_start = .1;
up_stop = .4;
up_value = 3;
down_value = -1;
x = linspace(0,10,200); %// x axis

%// Generate function
Borne = zeros(size(x)); %// initiallize
aux = rem(x,period);
ind = (aux>=up_start) & (aux<up_stop); %// index of "up" values
Borne(ind) = up_value;
Borne(~ind) = down_value;
```

[image]

Comment: +1, Nice answer, didn't think about using `rem`... and I'll be the one making you a moderator Luis! Congratz! =)

Comment: @RobertP. Hahaha, yes! Thank you! Now I have to figure out what being a moderator means, exactly... :-)

Comment: Thank you all for you answers, but I'm having some trouble using this solution: I pasted the code after the definition of the function Borne, but when I try to call it using a value `t`, i.e. when I write `borne(t)`, I get the error "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same." How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want steps at 2, 4, 6 etc. you could use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
t = (1:14).*0.1;
x(2:4:12) = -4;
x(4:4:14) = 4;
x(1) = 3;      
y = cumsum(x);
[t; y] = 
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1
```

The way this works is, you first create a vector that is +1 and -1 where you want the step to be. `cumsum` will take the cumulative sum of this vector, thus altering between 1 and 0.

If you want, you can plot this using [`stairs`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html).

## Update

With your values, this will be:

```
n = 8;      % Don't know the length of t 
t = (0:n).*0.1;
x = zeros(1, length(t));
x(2:4:length(t)) = -4;
x(4:4:length(t)) = 4;
x(1) = 3;      
y = cumsum(x);
[t; y] = 
   0.00000   0.10000   0.20000   0.30000   0.40000   0.50000   0.60000   0.70000
   3.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000   3.00000   3.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000   3.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

No complicated code is needed for something like this. You can use the [`square`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html) function, which is part of the Signal Processing toolbox that comes with most distributions of Matlab:

```
miny = -1;    % Minimum amplitude
maxy = 3;     % Maximum amplitude
period = 0.4; % Period in Hz, 1/frequency
duty = 0.5;   % Duty cycle, percentage of time spent at maxy
offset = 0.1; % Phase offset in sec.
t = 0:0.01:3;
y = 0.5*(maxy-miny)*square(2*pi*(t-offset)/period,duty*100)-miny;

figure;
plot(t,y)
axis([t(1) t(end) miny-0.1*(maxy-miny) maxy+0.1*(maxy-miny)])
```